# How to properly set up the React Web Server to use HTTPS protocol?

Tags: reactjs, windows, https

I'd like to configure the *React Web Server* to use `HTTPS` protocol on my *Windows 10* machine.

I've created locally trusted *CA* using `mkcert -install` and then generated the *SSL* certificate with `mkcert localhost` (like it's explained for e.g. [here](https://ncoughlin.com/posts/https-on-localhost-with-react/)).

Here is the *package.json* file excerpt for a *start* script I'm using:

```
"start": "set HTTPS=true&&set SSL_CRT_FILE=DiscogsApp.pem&&set SSL_KEY_FILE=DiscogsApp-key.pem&& react-scripts start",
```

Unfortunately sth. is still wrong because when i start the server (`npm start`) I'm getting the browser warning about not trusted site. The problems appears both on *FireFox* and *Opera* browsers.